# Blue outline of enemies

Tags: doom-eternal

Sometimes enemies in the game become outlined in blue, like in the following picture:

[image: blue outline]

It does not seem to be connected with outlining the enemies that are obstructed by the environment. Those are certainly not glory kills markers (when an enemy waits for a glory kill it remains static and the blue shade is all over it; here, however, the enemy remains alive, active, can attack and blue is just at the borders of its body). I think it might have something to do with using rocket launcher, but I am not sure. What does the blue outline mean?

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen this.  Are you sure its not staggered, maybe from a rocket blast?  And ready for a glory kill?

Comment: Might not be just the rocket launcher, as you have the plasma rifle out in that pic...

Comment: @GnomeSlice When enemy waits for a glory kill it remains static and the blue shade is all over it. Here, however, the enemy remains alive, active, can attack and the blue is just at the borders of its body.

Comment: @Jimmery I might have switched the weapon in the meantime. But, as I said, I am not sure rocket launcher was just a little guesswork of mine.

Comment: I've started seeing this happening now as well.  Also have no clue what it is.  Definitely happened when using the rocket launcher for me at least... a few times.  Once they get the outline [I can continue to see them through walls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NwULD.jpg)

Comment: I think this is a bug associated with the rocket launcher lock-on mod.  Once you complete the mastery for this attachment you then gain the ability to lock onto multiple enemies.  I believe that is what is giving the enemies this outline, but should not continue to highlight the enemies when you are not using the weapon.

Answer (score 1):

These are [Empowered Demons](https://doomwiki.org/wiki/Empowered_demon).

> Empowered demons are a game play mechanic which first appears in Doom Eternal, [...] Slightly stronger versions of the ordinary demons, they can appear in most of the game's levels as a dynamic element, and drop greater rewards when killed.
>
> [...] The initial conceit of empowered demons is that they were demons who had killed other players during their own campaigns, and that the empowered demons would gradually grow stronger unless eliminated.

Note: the wiki does state that the outline should be yellow, however I have seen it to appear blue sometimes (having had played very recently - I don't know if this is an update, or a UI choice to affect colors).

Additional Note: the only thing that is blocking the outline is the Revenant in front of it. Outlines for Empowered demons appear through solid objects, but not other Demons (which can make it much easier to spot [Spectres](https://doomwiki.org/wiki/Spectre_(Doom_Eternal)) for example). You can also see the opaque section of the back leg obscured behind the door frame.

[image]